# Big issue in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, interface

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04. First I tried to just run the DEMO, but it was really slow, so I decided to just install it immediately. I cleared all previous files, deleting Windows, and got Ubuntu installed.

My issue is basically that Ubuntu does not work as it should at all.

First of all the start-up is incredibly slow. Takes about 1 minute, whilst last time I used 12.04 and 12.10 it took about 5-10 seconds.

Second issue is that the whole interface is really, really buggy. Programs I open can not be minimized; well, they can, but just disappear (yet still running, so I can not re-open them.. firefox e.g). In addition to this, when I open a program I can not click in it with my cursor at all, until I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> twice. Problem is that once I can actually click within that specific window, I can not click anywhere else until I close it completely (which I have to do with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, because I can not even click the top-bar with the close, maximize & minimize buttons).

Once I have even touched the bar on the side (with the programs) I can never touch the desktop, nothing happens; neither right-click nor left-click, and I am unable to ever click the icons in top-right corner of the screen to turn off/restart computer etc.

A lot of issues, I know, but hopefully someone can help me. Perhaps it is a faulty install disc? Burnt it today, so I am unsure.

Comment: First, what is the computer make/model and specifications.

Answer (score 0):

These symptoms seem very odd. If you think it could be a disc problem, you should try installing from a USB stick. You might also want to download the disc image again because it may have been corrupted somehow.